# How to persist chat messages in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a chat application built in React, my intention is store the chat messages in localStorage. Following is the code for your reference

```
const [textMessages, setTextMessages] = useState([]);
const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.getItem('messages') // Doesn't load the stored data
      }, []);

const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        if (textValue != "") {

          const newData = []
          newData.push([...textMessages, textValue])
          setTextMessages([...textMessages, textValue]);
          localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(newData))

          setTextValue("");

        } else {
          return;
        }
      };

return (
<>
<button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
            Send Message
</button>
</>
)
```

What could be the best solution? Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-montalcini-bpdsp

Comment: Your `localStorage.getItem('messages')` should return the data, you're just not doing anything with it (E.g. storing it to a variable, formatting it, and setting it back into the state)

Comment: On loading the page data is missing

Comment: OK so its required to store data in variable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON string back into an array, and set your state:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const savedMessages = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('messages'))
    if (savedMessages !== null) {
        setTextMessages(savedMessages)
    }
}, []);
```

Other things that are worth thinking about but I won't include in the simple example:

- Consider wrapping the `JSON.parse()` in a try-catch, just in case the user has modified their local storage and it is now invalid JSON.
- Having the local storage key stored as a const prevents typos when setting/getting the item from multiple places (E.g. `const storageKey='messages'; localStorage.getItem(storageKey)`)

Comment: Throwing error 'textMessages  is not iterable'

Comment: OK error is gone  and data is also persisted in localStorage, but, messages are missing on loading